# How to use the today date in a variable

Tags: javascript, json

Im trying to get data from a JSON document, and in the document its ordered by dates.. so i want my page to load the todays date so i made a variable to get the todays date, but i dont understand how to use it. I just added .today in the sugString but that dont work for me.. Anyone know how i should do it? Here is my code!

[link to JSON document](https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetPriceList/v1/?appid=433850)

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
  dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
  mm='0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

var ourRequest2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest2.open('GET', 'https://api.opskins.com/IPricing/GetPriceList/v1/?appid=433850');
ourRequest2.onload = function() {
  var ourData2 = JSON.parse(ourRequest2.responseText);
  renderPinstripeJacketSug(ourData2)
};

ourRequest2.send();

function renderPinstripeJacketSug(data) {
  var sugString = data.response[ 'Skin: Pinstripe Suit Jacket' ].today.price;
  pinstripeJacketSug.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', sugstring);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried accessing like this...

```
var sugString = data.response['Skin: Pinstripe Suit Jacket'][today].price;
```

Comment: i tried that now but still i get this error message: main.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined
    at renderPinstripeJacketSug (main.js:61)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest2.onload (main.js:54)

Comment: I found the problem, the last date in the JSON is yesterdays date, is there a way i can make my today date to yesterdays date? :)

Comment: Try this...  var today = new Date(); today.setDate(today.getDate()-1);

Answer (score 0):

Have a try like this

```js
var data = {"status":1,"time":1481897448,"response":{"Skin: Pinstripe Suit Jacke":{"2016-12-15":{"price":10},"2016-12-16":{"price":10}}}}

 // this data you have received in the renderPinstripeJacketSug call, below code will go inside this function only.

var today = new Date();
var dateFormatted = today.toISOString().slice(0,10);
var price = ""


Object.keys(data.response["Skin: Pinstripe Suit Jacke"]).map(function(key, index) {

     if(key == dateFormatted)
      {
           price = data.response["Skin: Pinstripe Suit Jacke"][key].price;
     }
});

var sugString = price;

console.log(sugString);
```